# What are the chances of getting a legendary card?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have like the WORST luck of all time in getting legendary cards in Fallout Shelter. So that got me wondering, what are the chances of getting a legendary card?

Comment: As a sidenote, making a sockpuppet that obvious means there is absolutely no effort required to find it, delete it, and revert the upvotes.  Remember, voting for your own posts is a major no-no.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's a 0.0078 chance of getting one.

Comment: That's a pretty exact figure; mind pointing us to some sources?

Comment: Where did you get that figure?

Comment: This is an extremely hard number to believe, without a source. To that end, I'm going to assume it's fake until one is provided.

Comment: @Frank two accounts, same name, I'm sure we won't get a source